# Cannot get reference to layouts and id in res. folder

Tags: android, android-layout, import

This question has been up a couple of times but still I haven't found an answer that helped me.

1:st one: 
I cannot find any of my R.Layout.activity_article_detail and other layout xml files through reference. It stopped working after did a "clean project" in Eclipse and tried to build it up again.
I've tried removing and adding and removing the .R import but right now it wont find any of them. My layout files doesn't include a Capital letter, are spelled correcly.
code:

```
package martin.larsson.kopingsrssreader;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import martin.larsson.kopingsrssreader.R;

public class ArticleDetailActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_article_detail);
```

Second problem is it cant find my res.menu either. I got 2 files in it. detailmenu.xml and refreshmenu.xml. In both i cant find any of the id tags

```
    <item android:id="@+id/actionbar_markunread"
    <item android:id="@+id/actionbar_saveoffline"
    <item android:id="@+id/actionbar_refresh"
```

Does anyone got a clue?

SOLUTION: Uncheck "build automatically" and do a "clean project", and a Eclipse restart.

Comment: check it there is any errors i your any of the resource files

Comment: As far as i can see, all are correct. I got no errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Clean your project or restart the eclipse.
2. Look to the imports, the R imported maybe is not correct.
3. If anything is wrong in your layouts, new updates aren't added to the R file. Look at the errors panel, and possibly to a clean rebuild to see what errors are popping up.

Comment: I unchecked "Build automatically" under project and cleaned project. It worked.
Earlier I tried to use clean project and restart with the "build automatically" and it didn't give any result.

Answer (score 0):

if u have an error in any of the resource files `R` will show up red unless all Errors are fixed and the project is built